# pause a program (bash script) to a certain time

Tags: bash, shell-script, suspend, sleep

I want to pause a certain bash script for 30 minutes. Right now I use `sleep 1800` but that doesn't take into account time the laptop might be in suspend (sleep) state. Is there way to achieve this?

If, right now, it is 12:53 pm, I want to resume the program at 1:23 am. But in meantime, the computer can be in sleep state. If the computer sleeps until later than 1:23 am, then I want the program to resume immediately after resuming from sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe wrap it in a `while` loop and test if your at the scheduled time.

```
#!/bin/bash                                 

SOON=$(($(date +%s) + 1800))                                   
while [[ "$NOW" -le "$SOON" ]]; do                         
    sleep 1                            
    NOW=$(date +%s)                                     
done
```

The date idea can also be found in [this answer by chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30630599/4592084). The `+%s` makes `date` format the date in seconds since 1970 something. `$(( ))` just arithmetically adds the amount of seconds. Replace 1800 with any amount (probably best to test with a low amount and see if it works). `sleep 1` makes the script check the condition every second.